# A new editing format

Tags: discussion

Well, I edit a lot. But you don't use `this` or **this** or *this* to show important system/machine details like what ubuntu or package you want to install. Is there something you could use for that?

Comment: For packages, use `code format` please. Otherwise, use italics. However, going crazy with excessive formatting and similar is a really good way to get your edits rejected. Assume that the person will actually read your answer instead of just skimming it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking how to mark important parts.
In HTML we have `<em>` for *emphasis* which is by default rendered as *italics*.

So I usually use *italics* (preferable markdown: `*italics*`) to put emphasis on something.

Answer (score 10):

Well, when it comes to Markdown for package names, I highly encourage users to check out my [Ask Ubuntu Toolbar Buttons UserScript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2405/ask-ubuntu-toolbar-buttons-a-set-of-toolbar-buttons-for-ask-ubuntu-that-make-i). It adds four buttons to the toolbar:

[image]

The second button prompts you for a package name and then generates a nice, fancy-looking link like the one below:

[roundcube-plugins Install roundcube-plugins http://hostmar.co/software-small](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/roundcube-plugins)

Comment: Shameless plug is shameless.

Comment: Hey, totally acceptable as long as I disclose my affiliation (which I did).